# How to avoid View flicker during Android transition

Tags: android

I have got a strange issue with transitions between fragments.

I have a first fragment which has a list, a frame layout with another fragment and floating action button. Here is the XML:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:elevation="15dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_activity_info_fragment"
        android:name="com.better.alarm.presenter.InfoFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/info_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>

<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:elevation="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

It looks like that:

[image: here is how it looks in the preview]

Now I have a transition to another Fragment (fade).
Everything looks fine 8 times out of 10. But sometimes at the beginning of the animation the FrameLayout is brought to the front as if it had higher elevation than the action button. Bottom part of the button is then hidden behind the frame layout for a short while until the animation is finished.

Exactly the same issue occurs if I use the action bar from compat library.

Does anyone know how to avoid this occasional flicker?